# How to prevent Cross-Frame Scripting (XFS) in request parameter of spring boot controller with request method GET?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-boot, xss, csrf

On GET request how can request parameter be scanned for any security vulnerability.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/XX/YYY", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
public String myCustomMethod(Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
        @RequestParam(value = "a", required = false) String a,
        @RequestParam(value = "b", required = false) String b)
{

}
```

In this code sample I want to check if parameter a/b is infected with something like //"< i f r a m e src="http://www.goal.com/?"> .

Comment: Is your output going to be included in HTML?

Comment: yes, output will be included in HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prevention I use is to encode the untrusted input before adding to output as [suggested by OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content), the Open Web Application Security Project.

I use their ESAPI library. Find here links to

- [github project](https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy)
- [maven repo](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.owasp.esapi/esapi)
- [javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.1.0.1)

Once you have included the library, locate the `ESAPI.properties` and `validation.properties` files in the `configuration/.esapi` directory and copy them to your project's root (if you are using maven, `src/main/resources`). Those files are specifying the strategy for validation and encoding; I'm usually good with the defaults.

You can then use the encoder like this:

```
Encoder encoder = ESAPI.encoder();
String aSafe = encoder.encodeForHTML(a); 
String bSafe = encoder.encodeForHTML(b);
```